# =MATCH() returns wrong value

Tags: google-sheets, match, google-sheets-formula

Why doesn't [this](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AiNJOiic9NfFdG9GeXM4S21iWWp0MU9pMWtucUpMQ3c) work? I have the share of votes of different Finnish parties in the City of Jyväskylä in every region.

Every row shows one region, every column has the share of votes of every party. I'd like to add a column where Google Spreadsheet would find out which column has the maximum value on that particular row and then return the text on the header row of that column.

In other words I'd want to add "The biggest party column" that would show which party got the biggest share of votes in every region.

I think that should be possible using =max()-function to find out the maximum value, then using =match() function to give the column index number of the cell that has the biggest value on row and finally use =index()-function to return the party's name from header row.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 6):

MATCH needs a third argument of zero for your case (to get an exact match). Change formula to

`=INDEX(C$1:M$1,MATCH(MAX(C2:M2),C2:M2,0))`

Comment: A little correction to this answer, you would need the 0 in the index as well. So for it to work you need: =INDEX(C$1:M$1,0,MATCH(MAX(C2:M2),C2:M2,0)) Best,
Dom

Comment: Hello Dom - If the reference is a single row, as here, then you don't need to specify the row argument (because it can only be one row) so I think my suggestion works fine as it is

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but for an exact match (case sensitive) it seems setting the match parameter to 0 is broken. See the attached picture and linked spreadsheet:

https://i.imgur.com/bfVFZeo.png

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1kbrdmsIRugwcBhiGM5FUd63Maq6hzkNEYvMrx7uqSCA/edit?usp=sharing